# Trying to get discord bot to respond when certain person starts typing

Tags: discord.py

**The part I need help with is at the bottom**
Any suggestions and help will be greatly apricated.
Here is all the code:

```
 #Get Discord
import discord
# Client
client= discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
# Commands
 testing_channel = client.get_channel(781417659019034634)
 await testing_channel.send ('Ready')

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == 'why is corey sad':
      testing_channel = client.get_channel(781417659019034634)
      await testing_channel.send ('Because julia got a bf 0.2 secs after breaking up with him') 


@client.event
async def on_typing(channel, user, when):
    if user.id == 574638576155754498: 
        testing_channel = client.get_channel(781417659019034634)
        await testing_channel.send('Why')
```

Comment: and what's wrong with it?

Comment: also remove your token as fast as possible and change it!!!!! Someone can control your bot

Comment: I'll do that right now!And whenever the person types it dosent say the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically, you forgot to enable intents

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
```

I've enabled member intents so the `user` variable is not `None` in the `on_typing` event,
also enable privileged member intents in the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)

[Here's](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html?a-primer-to-gateway-intents) an introduction to intents

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Remember to accept the answer if it helped

Comment: Hahaha sorry didn't know you could do that, just did. Thanks again.